# I Try to request post but error Invalid URI " / " Rest API

Tags: node.js, request

```
const req = require('request')

let base  =  'https://openapi-v2.kucoin.com';
let endpoint = '/api/v1/orders';  
let url    = base + endpoint;   



req.post(url,params,config,(err,body,res)=>{
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(res)
})
```

i try to request post but error lnvalid URI " / " 
I don't know how to fix this.

[Error Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hxYN.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure Wrong part of the link

Comment: What are `params` and `config` ?

Comment: it's Access rest api

Comment: params =  data
config   = key rest api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `request`'s [document](https://github.com/request/request#readme), The `post` method does not receive 4 arguments. Set your config and data into the first argument:

```
request.post({
  url:'http://service.com/upload',
  form: {key:'value'}
}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ /* ... */ })
```

Also the order of `err,body,res` is incorrect.

Use something like this one:

```
req.post({
  url: url,
  params: data,
  X: config.X,
  Y: config.Y
}, (err,httpResponse,body)=>{
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(res)
})
```